# Question titles break mid-word on mobile

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web, mobile-safari

Question titles on the mobile site don't wrap properly, words break to the next line in the middle.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of text breaking]

Comment: This is happening since the latest mobile Web update. On both Samsung browser, android chrome, and ios. **It also happens in block quotes**. Seems the css for word wrap was removed or buggy.

Comment: Wait, it's not happening in quotes or text anymore, just titles.

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Fix should be ready soon.

Answer (score 5):

Fix for this issue has been released. It should be fixed now.

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

Comment: Thanks, all good now.